# js code running in console but not by live server

Tags: javascript, html

I am biginner coder in js. I am trying to make a counter till 100. The given code works fine in console but counter dosent work in browser by live server.
`**JS**

```
var count=1;
setInterval(()=>{
    if(count!=100)
    {
         count++;
         k.innerHTML=count  
    }
},10)
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
        body{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 80vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p onclick="hell()">counter</p>
    <div><span id="oe">1</span>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-play"></i>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Countdown reached 100. It works perfectly in browser.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```js
        let count=0;
        let timer = 1;
        let k = null;
        let para = null;
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onDomContentLoaded);
        function onDomContentLoaded(e){
            k = document.getElementById("oe");
            para = document.getElementById("myParagraph");
            para.addEventListener("click",hell);
        }
        function countFunction(){
            if(count<100){
                count++;
                console.log(count);
                k.innerHTML=count;
            }
            if(count===100){
                clearInterval(timer);
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        function hell(){
            if(count===0){
                timer = setInterval(countFunction,10);
            }
        }
```

```css
        body{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 80vh;
        }
```

```html
        <p id="myParagraph">counter</p>
        <div><span id="oe">1</span>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-play"></i>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that totally gives the answer but what makes me really confused is whether a normal program of DOM work on browser loads by default or if we have to use saperate function or use document.onload on every single DOM project.

Comment: @GhimireSuraj  if the issue is solved please mark it as solved.
If You have another question, please post it as a new topic.
I will be happy to help you.